# Matlab removing duplicate matrix value

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix with a shape like below. I want to delete rows with duplicate values ​​in the first column and leaving row with the smallest number of duplicate values ​​in the second column. my matrix
`d =

```
 1     1
 2     1
 4     1
 8     2
 2     2
 5     4
 2     4
 6     4
 7     3
```

`
I want to remove duplicate number 2 in the first column and leaving the row with the smallest number of duplicate values ​​in the second row
result required:

```
 1     1
 4     1
 8     2
 2     2
 5     4
 6     4
 7     3
```

Thanks for the helps. best regard.

Comment: The last lines in the input and output matrices are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a function that finds the minimal duplicate from the right column, given an index from the left column:

   ```
   function Out = getMinDuplicate (Index, Data)
     Candidates = Data(Data(:,1) == Index, :); Candidates = Candidates(:, 2);
     Hist = histc (Data(:,2), [1 : max(Data(:,2))]);
     [~,Out] = min (Hist(Candidates)); Out = Candidates(Out);
   end
   ```
2. Call this function for all unique values in column 1:

   ```
   >> [unique(d(:,1)), arrayfun(@(x) getMinDuplicate(x, d), unique(d(:,1)))]
   ans =
        1     1
        2     2
        4     1
        5     4
        6     4
        7     3
        8     2
   ```

(where `d` is your data array).

Comment: You're welcome ... though I sense from your comment that you're not quite sure why? :p  Would you like me to expand the answer with a more detailed explanation below?

Comment: But your output matrix is not the same as that in question. Thus your solution is not fully correct. And do not worry you will not get "-" from me. Moreover, in my opinion, this solution uses unnecessary code. To obtain the output matrix using my answer it is necessary to use just three lines: `d = sortrows(d,2); [~, ind] = unique(d(:,1)); d(ind,:)`. The `unique` uses the first entry of duplicated values, so it uses the minimum value of the duplicates if **you have previously sorted the lines in the second column**.

Comment: @AlexanderKorovin I apologise my friend, I didn't mean to offend you with my comment. I wasn't being critical about your code length or technique. I'm just pointing out I think you misunderstood the question and solved the wrong problem. You're right about the output in my answer being 'sorted' and therefore 'technically not fully correct' ... I assumed from the wording that OP didn't really care about that, so I opted not to litter my answer with unnecessary 'custom sorting' code, though, obviously if OP asked me to I would happily update it. But, that aside, it's solving the correct problem.

Comment: thank you my friend Alexander Korovin, your answer is correct and Tasos Papastylianou yours too. I think my question is ambiguous. all the answers I get I use in my work. I appreciate to all answers.

Answer (score 2):

We can sort the array regards to first column and replace elements of second column by their descending count
to obtain this array:

```
   1   3
   2   3
   2   3
   2   2
   4   3
   5   3
   6   3
   7   1
   8   2
```

Then if we apply unique to this array indices of desirable rows can be obtained and then then those rows can be extracted:

```
   1   1
   2   2
   4   1
   5   4
   6   4
   7   3
   8   2
```

If oreder of original data should be preserved more step required that  commented in the code.

```
a=[...
 1     1
 2     1
 4     1
 8     2
 2     2
 5     4
 2     4
 6     4
 7     3];
 %steps to replace counts of each element of column2 with it
 [a2_sorted, i_a2_sorted] = sort(a(:,2));
 [a2_sorted_unique, i_a2_sorted_unique] = unique(a2_sorted);
 h = hist(a2_sorted, a2_sorted_unique);
 %count = repelems(h, [1:numel(h); h]);%octave
 count = repelem(h, h);
 [~,a2_back_idx] = sort(i_a2_sorted);
 count = count (a2_back_idx);
 b = [a(:,1) , count.'];
 %counts shoule be sorted in descending order 
 %because the unique function extracts last element from each category
 [b_sorted i_b_sorted] =sortrows(b,[1 -2]);
 [~, i_b1_sorted_unique] = unique(b_sorted(:,1));
 c = [b_sorted(:,1) , a(i_b_sorted,2)];
 out = c(i_b1_sorted_unique,:)
 %more steps to recover the original order
 [~,b_back_idx] = sort(i_b_sorted);
 idx_logic = false(1,size(a,1));
 idx_logic(i_b1_sorted_unique) = true;
 idx_logic = idx_logic(b_back_idx);
 out = c(b_back_idx(idx_logic),:)
```

Comment: thank you for your solution...but why can I use repelem function?it show error 'Undefined function 'repelem' for input arguments of type 'double'.'

Comment: @wee repelem introduced in matlab 2015a then version below that do not have this function. see this link for a loop based implementation: http://rextester.com/VBDH46682

Comment: no wonder it can't works, because i use matlab 2013b..thank you so much for your info..
best regard..